# Валидация полей при нажатии клавиши и блокировка кнопки

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Суть скрипта, это при нажатии кнопки (keyup) проверить правильность их заполнения + если один из элементов имеет класс (error) то кнопка отправить становится неактивной
Проблема в том, что приходится лишние кнопки на клавиатуре нажимать, что бы событие сработало, как этот скрипт сделать более корректным?

Код страницы:

```
<div class="modal-title">Ваши данные</div>
            <div class="modal-buy-form-phone">
                    <input type="text" class="cart-input cart-input_block" data-field="receiverAppartment" id="zakazYouName">
                    <label for="js-cart_get_appartment" class="cart-label_moved">Ваше имя</label>
                    <div class="error-box"></div>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-buy-form-phone">
                <input type="tel" class="cart-input cart-input_block"  data-field="customerPhone" placeholder="+7 777 000 00 00" value="" id="zakazYouPhone">
                <label class="cart-label_transformed" for="js-cart_send_phone">Ваш телефон <i>*</i></label>
                <div class="error-box"></div>
            </div>
<button id='add-shop-button' disabled="disabled" onclick="sendZakaz(<?=$item['id']; ?>);" class="modal-send-button">Перейти к оплате</button>
```

Код Jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('.setimg').click(function() {
    $('#bigimg').attr('src', ($(this).attr('src')));
   })

   $('#zakazYouName, #zakazYouMail').on("keyup", function(){

        if($("#zakazYouName").hasClass("not-error")) {
            if($("#zakazYouMail").hasClass("not-error")) {
                $("#add-shop-button").removeAttr('disabled');
                $("#add-shop-button").removeClass('error').addClass('not-error');
            }
        } 


        if($("#zakazYouName, #zakazYouMail").hasClass("error")) {
                $("#add-shop-button").attr('disabled', true);
                $("#add-shop-button").removeClass('not-error').addClass('error');
        }

        if($("#zakazYouMail").hasClass("error")) {
                $("#add-shop-button").attr('disabled', true);
                $("#add-shop-button").removeClass('not-error').addClass('error');
        }


         var id = $(this).attr('id');
         var val = $(this).val();

       switch(id)
       {
             // Проверка поля "Имя"
             case 'zakazYouName':
                var rv_name = /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+$/;


                if(val.length > 2 && val != '' && rv_name.test(val))
                {

                   $(this).removeClass('error').addClass('not-error');
                   $(this).next('.error-box').text('Принято')
                                             .css('color','green')
                                             .animate({'paddingLeft':'10px'},400)
                                             .animate({'paddingLeft':'5px'},400);
                }


                else
                {
                   $(this).removeClass('not-error').addClass('error');
                   $(this).next('.error-box').html('поле "Имя" обязательно для заполнения<br>, длина имени должна составлять не менее 2 символов<br>, поле должно содержать только русские или латинские буквы')
                                              .css('color','red')
                                              .animate({'paddingLeft':'10px'},400)
                                              .animate({'paddingLeft':'5px'},400);
                }
            break;

           case 'zakazYouMail':
               var rv_email = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/;
               if(val != '' && rv_email.test(val))
               {
                  $(this).removeClass('error').addClass('not-error');
                  $(this).next('.error-box').text('Принято')
                                            .css('color','green')
                                            .animate({'paddingLeft':'10px'},400)
                                            .animate({'paddingLeft':'5px'},400);
               }
               else
               {
                  $(this).removeClass('not_error').addClass('error');
                  $(this).next('.error-box').html('поле "Email" обязательно для заполнения<br>, поле должно содержать правильный email-адрес<br>')
                                             .css('color','red')
                                             .animate({'paddingLeft':'10px'},400)
                                             .animate({'paddingLeft':'5px'},400);
               }
           break;

       }

     });
});
```

Comment: уже понял в чем проблема, я условия ставлю перед тем, как задаю им классы error и not-error